# Customize what notifications received by user

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

i googled already but didn't find a suitable answer out there!
what i want is something similar to this image

[image]

APNs already setup and working.

my question is how can i customize what kind of notifications user will received. so users can select what they want to received.

is this a backend related stuff or iOS app?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is a full backend "related stuff".
You have to keep track of your user's settings server-side and only send notifications for what they want.
There is no such thing as a "notification's topic filter" in iOS.